# Is there a way to use chain and group with celery?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, rabbitmq, celery

Im building a solution using python, django rest framework, celery and rabbitmq to run some tasks in my api project. However some tasks may be done in parallel and others not.

I tried this solution using chord and group, but in these two ways the last task(task_9) never is executed, all the others previous tasks are executed with success. When i tried chord i put task_9 as a callback function, but even this doesn't work. Here is an example of my code.

```
chain(task_1.si(registry_id, name) | 
                  task_2.si(registry_id, name) |
                  task_3.si(registry_id, name) |
                  group(task_4.s(task_3_result), 
                        task_5.s(task_3_result), 
                        task_6.s(task_3_result), 
                        task_7.s(task_3_result), 
                        task_8.s(task_3_result),
                       ) | 
                  task_9.si(registry_id, name)
                  ).apply_async()
```